# ERROR: gcloud failed to load: No module named 'googlecloudsdk.third_party.apis.binaryauthorization.v1alpha2.binaryauthorization_v1alpha2_messages'

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install gcloud CLI on macOS 64-bit(x86_64) by following these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

When I run `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh` I get this error:

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud CLI!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benkula/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 30, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk import gcloud_main
  File "/Users/benkula/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud_main.py", line 37, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.command_lib.util.apis import yaml_command_translator
  File "/Users/benkula/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/apis/yaml_command_translator.py", line 39, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.command_lib.iam import iam_util
  File "/Users/benkula/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/iam/iam_util.py", line 85, in <module>
    binaryauthorization_message_v1alpha2 = core_apis.GetMessagesModule(
  File "/Users/benkula/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/apis.py", line 339, in GetMessagesModule
    return __import__(api_def.apitools.messages_full_modulepath,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlecloudsdk.third_party.apis.binaryauthorization.v1alpha2.binaryauthorization_v1alpha2_messages'
```

`./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` shows a similar error:

```
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: No module named 'googlecloudsdk.third_party.apis.binaryauthorization.v1alpha2.binaryauthorization_v1alpha2_messages'
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.command_lib.util.apis import yaml_command_translator
    from googlecloudsdk.command_lib.iam import iam_util
    binaryauthorization_message_v1alpha2 = core_apis.GetMessagesModule(
    return __import__(api_def.apitools.messages_full_modulepath,

This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.

Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3

If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable.

If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

Python executable seems to be where it should be, so I don't think that's the problem. I can see it when I run `ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`.

`python3 -V` shows `Python 3.8.9`.

What can I do to install gcloud CLI successfully?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used this command instead, and it worked for me:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Found here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive.